# Vitis hls : Compare performance with and without hardware

Tags: hlsl, xilinx

I am new to vitis hls and to get started I have been tasked with creating a simple script with 3 nested loops in order to understand how beneficial is using hardware to do certain calculation.

So basically its something stupid like this:

```
int do_for_hw(int max){
    int count = 0;

    loop1_1 : for (int i = 0; i < max; i++){
        loop1_2 : for (int j = 0; j < max; j++){
            loop1_3 : for (int k = 0; k < max; k++)
                count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This is a function in a separate file, and its getting called in the main.
I am looking to compare the difference in real time performance when the above function runs in hardware

So at first I run the C simulation, and get this log file
https://pastebin.pl/view/eb7d6cbd

And then after I Run C synthesis, I run Co Simulation and get this log file
https://pastebin.pl/view/7cd758c3

I am looking to compare the performance I would get in each occasion.

- ### Question 1:

Looking at the log I see that the **C simulation**, there are Total CPU user time, Total CPU system time  and total elapsed time, times and as I understand it, the delay of running the program, and the time that the user would have to wait is the Total CPU user time. Correct?

- ### Question 2:

Looking at the log I see that the **Co simulation**, there are the same times in the end but there is a section before that (lines 90 - 96) and in the end of that section, it says that the time needed was 265ns.
So is this the time required to run just the function in hardware,  is this the time needed to run the whole program?

- ### Question 3

If this test makes sense, I know it is too simple but I have to start from somewhere, in order to compare the real time performance of my **main** with and without hardware doing some of the job, do I compare the times at **INFO: [HLS 200-112]**, do I compare the times from **INFO: [HLS 200-112]** for C simulation and the times from **## Run all - ## Finish called at time : ...** for the Co simulation, am I completely wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't post links to code, please include the code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues I see before even start to analyze the questions.

#### Remark #1: HLS basics

First of all, HLS tries to abstract away from the HW and FPGA design but you can't see your code as pure software. You need to think about how it will be implemented in hardware, especially when comparing performances. At the end of the day HLS is just another way of describing your architecture. If you don't have an end architecture in mind, you'll have little help from the compiler.

#### Remark #2: Compiler optimizations

You test is a bad one, because any compiler will just collapse either the entire loop into

```
int do_for_hw(int max){
    return max*max*max;
}
```

Or at least a single loop:

```
int do_for_hw(int max){
    loop1_1 : for (int i = 0; i < max*max*max; i++){
        count += 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

#### Remark #3: Performance indicators

In fpga hardware there are mainly two ways of describing performance requirements: **latency** and **throughput**. What do you want to measure? Latency is how much time it will be required to produce the first result. Throughput is how often you get a result when the hardware is running with a full pipeline.

There are ways in HLS to aid the tool into producing pipelined or unrolled loops, mainly with `#pragma unroll` etc..

#### Remark #4: Software environment

The processor and software world will have its own performance gains based on a myriad of reasons. Cache, branch prediction, paging, scheduling. Are you comparing it to a general purpose processor, or a dedicated one? Will you run your comparison with an OS or a bare metal application?

#### Remark #5: Task is not clear

You should bring all these concerns to whoever tasked you to do this comparison. There is little sense and even less value in having this comparison in general. Some algorithms are perfect for hardware, others will perform worse. Some architectures are specific for solving a problem, others don't. Some FPGA approaches can be faster than the GP processor equivalent, but maybe can't scale up. Finding a comparison between an abstract application, with no specific goal in mind, is a waste of time.